# Wingpanel adds shadow and defaults to white font after restart on light background

Tags: release-hera, wingpanel, wallpaper, bugs, text

There's a feature in elementary that depending on your background being light, switches the font to dark and removes the text-shadow, this seems to reset upon (re-)boot and you have to apply the same wallpaper again to get the proper dark text back.

Is there a known solution? note that I freshly installed today: elementary OS 5.1.3 Hera and updated all it offered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now until that bug is fixed, you can force the light background state in your `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` - if the file and subfolder does not exist, just create them.

```
.composited-indicator > revealer label,
.composited-indicator > revealer image,
.composited-indicator > revealer spinner,
.panel.color-light .composited-indicator > revealer label,
.panel.color-light .composited-indicator > revealer image,
.panel.color-light .composited-indicator > revealer spinner {
    color: alpha (#000, 0.65);
    text-shadow:
        0 0 2px alpha (#fff, 0.3),
        0 1px 0 alpha (#fff, 0.25);
    -gtk-icon-shadow:
        0 0 2px alpha (#fff, 0.3),
        0 1px 0 alpha (#fff, 0.25);
}
```

If you'd want to have light on dark background instead, modify it to be:

```
.composited-indicator > revealer label,
.composited-indicator > revealer image,
.composited-indicator > revealer spinner,
.panel.color-light .composited-indicator > revealer label,
.panel.color-light .composited-indicator > revealer image,
.panel.color-light .composited-indicator > revealer spinner {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow:
        0 0 2px alpha (#000, 0.3),
        0 1px 2px alpha (#000, 0.6);
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -gtk-icon-shadow:
        0 0 2px alpha (#000, 0.3),
        0 1px 2px alpha (#000, 0.6);
}
```

---

The hint at the solution was found on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/ewrd0r/how_to_make_the_top_panel_transparent_even_in_the/fg6047v/), for history sake a quote:

> Take a look at this css in wingpanel's source. If you were to copy and
>   paste that into your ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css, you should be able to
>   override the color of the icons. I've highlighted the part for when
>   the panel is on a light background. If you set the properties to the
>   same values in both sections, the icons should always be those colors
>   (you could copy the values from the first section to the second to
>   always have white icons, or copy the values from the second section to
>   the first to always have black icons). To demonstrate, I made
>   wingpanel have red text and icons.

The source mentioned is here: https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/blob/master/data/styles/application.css